# Number of different colourings of nodes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, polya-counting-theory

Consider a tree where each node has 2 subnodes, with a total of 7 nodes. So the maximum level of the tree is 2. Each node can be coloured white or black. Two colourings are equivalent if the one is about to enter in another by changing the left and right subtrees.

What is the corresponding permutation group? And what is the total number of different colourings?

Now I want to solve this with the theory of Polya. But I don't even know which permutation group belongs to this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tree looks like

```
   1
  / \
 2   3
/ \ / \
4 5 6 7
```

and the relevant permutation group for the Pólya counting theorem is the group of permutations where we say "two colorings are equivalent if they are related by one of these permutations".

So in this case the relevant permutions are those that interchange the left and right subtress of one of the inner nodes, that is,
$$\begin{align} x &= (23)(46)(57) & \text{(swap children of 1)} \\
y &= (45) &\text{(swap children of 2)} \\
z &= (67) &\text{(swap children of 3)} \end{align}$$
and all permutations that can be written as products of these.

So the first step is to figure out which croup these $x$, $y$, and $z$ generate. You could do that simply by computing all of the possible products of group elements until you don't find any more, but it is quicker to go about it algebraically and observe that the relations
$$ x^2=y^2=z^2=e \qquad yx = xz \qquad zx = xy \qquad zy=yz $$
(which are easy to check) imply that every element in the group can be written as
$$ x^iy^jz^k \qquad i,j,k\in\{0,1\} $$

So there are 8 elements that you can enumerate in a systematic way and then apply Pólya's theorem.

Comment: Very nice. (+1). Do you want to do the Polya Enumeration part yourself? I wouldn't want to enter in a race with your work.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: I'm planning to leave that part to the OP. :)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I am trying it with Polya, but I get stuck. Why there are 8 elements? Beside $x$, $y$ and $z$, I only see the permutation $(23)(47)(56)$.

Comment: @clubkli: Because each of $i$, $j$ and $k$ in $x^iy^jz^k$ can be either $0$ or $1$, so there are $x^0y^0z^0=e$, $x^0y^0z^1=z$, $x^0y^1z^0=y$, $x^0y^1z^1=yz$ and so forth ... And $(47)(56)$ is not in the group at all -- all the valid permutations preserve the parent-child relation, but $(47)(56)$ switches $4$ from being a child of $2$ to being a child of $3$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Then $xy = (65)$, $xz = (47)$, $yz = (67)$ and $xyz = (65)$. The cycle index is then given by $\displaystyle \frac{1}{8} \cdot (x_1 ^7 + x_1 x_2 ^3 +  6\cdot x_1 ^5 x_2)$. Substitute 2 into this equation don't give the desired answer of 42, which I saw at your other answer.

Comment: @clubkli: How do you get $xy=(65)$, for example? Since $x=(23)(46)(57)$ and $y=(45)$, we have $xy=(23)(46)(57)(45)=(23)(4756)$. Similarly, your calculations of $xz$ and $xyz$ are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Counting without Pólya**

I think this is easier than using the Pólya theorem for this particular question: Let $a_n$ be the number of different colorings of a tree with $n$ levels. (So concretely you're looking for $a_3$).

Clearly we have $a_1=2$.

For $a_{n+1}$ we can choose the color of the root node in $2$ ways. For each of these ways the subtrees can either be equivalent (in $a_n$ ways) or different (in $\binom{a_n}2=\frac{a_n(a_n-1)}2$ ways). So we have
$$ a_{n+1} = 2\left(a_n+\frac{a_n(a_n-1)}2\right) = a_n(a_n+1) $$

Then finding $a_3$ is just a matter of applying this recurrence twice:

$$\begin{align} a_1 &= 2 \\ a_2 &= 2\cdot 3 = 6 \\ a_3 &= 6 \cdot 7 = 42 \end{align} $$

These numbers form sequence [A007018](https://oeis.org/A007018) in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which gives a number of other combinatorial meanings for them.

Comment: (+1). Very nice generalization. I just know if I start to work on this one someone else will submit 30 seconds before I finish typesetting my work. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would  like to make a  first and quite basic  contribution using the
Polya Enumeration Theorem. This  certainly admits improvement, as here
we are enumerating all permutations  in the cycleindex $Z(Q_n)$ of the
permutation  group $Q_n$ that  permutes  the vertices of  these rooted
full unordered binary trees  on $n$ levels. The  reader is  invited to
contribute a cycle index formula that classifies permutations by their
cycle structure instead of computing all permutations.

Here are some cycle indices: this is the cycle index for three levels.
$$Z(Q_3) =
1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{7}+1/4\,{a_{{1}}}^{5}a_{{2}}
\\+1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{2}+1
/4\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{3}+1/4\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}.$$

This is the index for four levels:
$$Z(Q_4) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{15}}{128}}+1/32\,{a_{{1}}}^{13}a_{{2}}+{
\frac {3\,{a_{{1}}}^{11}{a_{{2}}}^{2}}{64}}+1/16\,{a_{{1}}}^
{9}{a_{{2}}}^{3}\\+1/32\,{a_{{1}}}^{9}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}+{\frac {9
\,{a_{{1}}}^{7}{a_{{2}}}^{4}}{128}}+1/16\,{a_{{1}}}^{7}{a_{{
2}}}^{2}a_{{4}}\\+1/32\,{a_{{1}}}^{5}{a_{{2}}}^{5}+1/32\,{a_{{
1}}}^{5}{a_{{2}}}^{3}a_{{4}}+1/32\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{6
}+1/16\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{4}a_{{4}}\\+1/16\,a_{{1}}{a_{{
2}}}^{7}+1/32\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}+1/8\,
a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{5}a_{{4}}+1/16\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{3}{a_{{4
}}}^{2}\\+1/8\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}+1/8\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}
a_{{4}}a_{{8}}.$$

The  cycleindex  $Z(Q_5)$  can  also  be computed.
Here is an excerpt:
$$\cdots+
{\frac {5\,{a_{{1}}}^{5}{a_{{2}}}^{5}{a_{{4}}}^{4}}{512}}+{\frac {{a_{
{1}}}^{5}{a_{{2}}}^{7}a_{{4}}a_{{8}}}{256}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{
2}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{4}a_{{8}}}{64}}+{\frac {a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{5}{a_{{4}
}}^{5}}{64}}\\+1/32\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{a_{{8}}}^{2}+1/32\,a_{{
1}}{a_{{2}}}^{9}{a_{{4}}}^{3}+1/32\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{3}{a_{{4}}}^{4}a
_{{8}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{29}a_{{2}}}{4096}}\\+{\frac {7\,{a_{{1}}}^{27}
{a_{{2}}}^{2}}{8192}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{25}{a_{{2}}}^{3}}{512}}+{
\frac {59\,{a_{{1}}}^{23}{a_{{2}}}^{4}}{16384}}+{\frac {11\,{a_{{1}}}^
{21}{a_{{2}}}^{5}}{2048}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{25}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}}{4096}}
+{\frac {3\,{a_{{1}}}^{23}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{4}}}{2048}}\\+{\frac {15\,{a_
{{1}}}^{21}{a_{{2}}}^{3}a_{{4}}}{4096}}+{\frac {13\,{a_{{1}}}^{19}{a_{
{2}}}^{4}a_{{4}}}{2048}}+{\frac {3\,{a_{{1}}}^{19}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{4}
}}^{2}}{4096}}\\+{\frac {43\,{a_{{1}}}^{17}{a_{{2}}}^{5}a_{{4}}}{4096}}+
{\frac {7\,{a_{{1}}}^{17}{a_{{2}}}^{3}{a_{{4}}}^{2}}{2048}}+{\frac {{a
_{{1}}}^{17}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}}{1024}}
+\cdots$$

This  yields  the
following sequence  for $$Z(Q_n)(B+W)_{B=1, W=1} = Z(Q_n; 2,2,2,\ldots)$$  (colorings with at most two colors):
$$2, 6, 42, 1806, 3263442,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A007018](https://oeis.org/A007018)
as was discovered by the author of the accepted answer.

For the special case of three levels we get the subsituted cycle index
$$1/8\, \left( B+W \right) ^{7}+1/4\, \left( B+W \right) ^{5} \left( {B}
^{2}+{W}^{2} \right) +1/8\, \left( B+W \right) ^{3} \left( {B}^{2}+{W}
^{2} \right) ^{2}\\+1/4\, \left( B+W \right)  \left( {B}^{2}+{W}^{2}
 \right) ^{3}+1/4\, \left( B+W \right)  \left( {B}^{2}+{W}^{2}
 \right)  \left( {B}^{4}+{W}^{4} \right)$$

which expands  to the detailed classification according  to the number
of black and white nodes
$${B}^{7}+3\,{B}^{6}W+7\,{B}^{5}{W}^{2}+10\,{B}^{4}{W}^{3}+10\,{B}^{3}{W
}^{4}+7\,{B}^{2}{W}^{5}+3\,B{W}^{6}+{W}^{7}.$$

E.g.  the coefficient  on $B^6  W$ is  three because  there  are three
orbits of nodes.

For the coefficient on $B^5 W^2$ we get the seven possibilities:

1. root node, node on level two
2. root node, node on level three
3. two nodes on level two
4. one  node  on level  two,  one  node  adjacent  to it  on  level
   three
5. one node on  level two,  one node  not adjacent  to it  on level
   three
6. two siblings on level three
7. two non-siblings on level three.

This is the Maple code for this computation, algorithmically extremely
straighforward:  enumerate all  possible combinations  of  keeping two
subtrees of a node in order or flipping them, compute the automorphism
that results  and factor  it into cycles  for the contribution  to the
cycle index.

```
pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1;

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;


pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;


bf_build_tree :=
proc(levels, curlev, label, flips)
    local left, right;

    if curlev = levels then
        return [label];
    fi;

    left := bf_build_tree(levels, curlev+1,
                          2*label, flips);
    right := bf_build_tree(levels, curlev+1,
                           2*label+1, flips);

    if flips[label] = 1 then
        return [label, right, left];
    else
        return [label, left, right];
    fi;
end;

bf_collect_autom :=
proc(tree, label, res)
    res[tree[1]] := label;

    if nops(tree) = 3 then
        bf_collect_autom(tree[2], 2*label, res);
        bf_collect_autom(tree[3], 2*label+1, res);
    fi;
end;



pet_cycleind_bf_tree :=
proc(levels)
    option remember;
    local res, ind, flips, allflips, autom, q, src, aut;

    res := 0; allflips := 2^(levels-1)-1;

    for ind from 2^allflips to 2^(allflips+1)-1 do
        flips := convert(ind, base, 2);

        autom := table();
        bf_collect_autom(bf_build_tree(levels, 1, 1, flips),
                         1, autom);

        src := [seq(q, q=1..2^levels-1)];
        aut := [seq(autom[q], q=1..2^levels-1)];

        res := res + pet_autom2cycles(src, aut);
    od;

    res/2^allflips;
end;


bf_2colorings :=
proc(levels)
    option remember;
    local ind;

    ind := pet_cycleind_bf_tree(levels);
    ind := pet_varinto_cind(B+W, ind);

    subs({B=1, W=1}, ind);
end;

bf_2coloringsX :=
proc(levels)
    option remember;
    local ind, q;

    ind := pet_cycleind_bf_tree(levels);
    subs({seq(a[2^q]=2, q=0..levels-1)}, ind);
end;
```